# Unable to run yew's documentation sample

Tags: rust, yew, trunk-rs

I am trying to build the sample app from the yew documentation ([here](https://yew.rs/docs/getting-started/build-a-sample-app)) and I am getting the error below.  If feels that it's something wrong with my environment since there are only 3 files to change for the app.

Any input is welcome.

```
osboxes@osboxes:~/src/rust-learning/yewwwww$ trunk serve
2023-03-31T18:14:01.101996Z  INFO  starting build
2023-03-31T18:14:01.102723Z  INFO spawning asset pipelines
2023-03-31T18:14:01.208652Z  INFO building yewwwww
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.23s
2023-03-31T18:14:01.485763Z  INFO fetching cargo artifacts
2023-03-31T18:14:01.743985Z  INFO processing WASM for yewwwww
2023-03-31T18:14:01.780445Z  INFO using system installed binary app=wasm-bindgen version=0.2.84
2023-03-31T18:14:01.780708Z  INFO calling wasm-bindgen for yewwwww
error: failed getting Wasm module for '/home/osboxes/src/rust-learning/yewwwww/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/debug/yewwwww.wasm'

Caused by:
    0: failed to parse bytes
    1: unexpected character '\0'
            --> <anon>:1:1
             |
           1 | 
             | ^
2023-03-31T18:14:02.182340Z ERROR ❌ error
error from HTML pipeline

Caused by:
    0: error from asset pipeline
    1: wasm-bindgen call returned a bad status
2023-03-31T18:14:02.182519Z  INFO  serving static assets at -> /
2023-03-31T18:14:02.182563Z  INFO  server listening at http://127.0.0.1:8080
cargo install --locked wasm-bindgen-cli^Cosboxes@osboxes:~/src/rust-learning/yewwwww$
```

Not sure what's wrong with my environment.  Here's my code

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "yewwwww"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
yew = { version = "0.20.0", features = ["csr"] }
```

**src/main.rs**

```
use yew::prelude::*;

#[function_component]
fn App() -> Html {
    let counter = use_state(|| 0);
    let onclick = {
        let counter = counter.clone();
        move |_| {
            let value = *counter + 1;
            counter.set(value);
        }
    };

    html! {
        <div>
            <button {onclick}>{ "+1" }</button>
            <p>{ *counter }</p>
        </div>
    }
}

fn main() {
    yew::Renderer::<App>::new().render();
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Yew App</title>
    </head>
</html>
```

**rustup show**

```
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/osboxes/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
beta-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
1.61.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.68.2 (9eb3afe9e 2023-03-27)
```